# using image picker on windows phone dose not wait until picking an image

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone, c#-5.0

on windows phone 8 i have a function that get an image from image library and should send it to the server as base string however when calling pick image it transfer me to library page but dose not wait till i pick it continues to send empty data to the server.

```
public void Chplaceimg(string PlaceID)
{
    YOimage changeplaceimg = new YOimage();

    if (changeplaceimg.pickImage() != null)
    {
        var pairs = new List<KeyValuePair<string, string>>
        {
           new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("id", _id),
           new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("image", changeplaceimg._base64Image),
           new KeyValuePair<string, string> ("place", PlaceID)
        };
        var serverData = serverConnection.connect("image.php", pairs);
    }
}

public bool pickImage()
{
    var photoChooserTask = new PhotoChooserTask();
    photoChooserTask.Completed += PhotoChooserTaskCompleted;
    photoChooserTask.Show();
    return true;
}

//run function convertToBase64 when an image is choosed
private void PhotoChooserTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
       convertToBase64(e);
    }

}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to make service call as part of `PhotoChooserTaskCompleted` callback.

```
//run function convertToBase64 when an image is choosed
private void PhotoChooserTaskCompleted(object sender, PhotoResult e)
{
    if (e.TaskResult == TaskResult.OK)
    {
        // send data to server here
        convertToBase64(e);
    }
}
```

Comment: but functions and parameters are in different classes

Comment: So reorganize it, to make that possible. There is no other way, because WP is all async, and based on callbacks.